# QGIS SegY Compatibility

Tags: qgis, vector

I am currently having a problem importing SegY files into QGIS. Following the 2.14 update, SegY compatibility should be available to bring in the navigation stored within the file as a vector layer. Has anyone else had problems importing these files? It never seems to work despite being a support GDAL layer. Any ideas as to why this might occur?